# Calculate height of styled-components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

For styled-components, how can I fetch the height of any particular div?
For e.g.., in the below example, how can I get the height(100px) of Outer tag,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const Outer = styled.div`
    height: "100px";
    border: 1px solid black;
  `;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Outer>Inside</Outer>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I have tried `Outer.height()` but it doesn't work. How can I get the height of Outer tag?

Comment: If you _truly_ wanted to get the value entered via styled components you can look into the stylesheet the library builds and parse it. I've adapted my code from another answer for you. https://codesandbox.io/s/1y5rmvxlkl - however this is (usually) overkill. Deve's answer will likely suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add reference to get size of `Outer` and do `this.outerRef.current.clientHeight`

Something like that :

```
const Outer = styled.div`
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
`;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.outerRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      outerHeight: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ outerHeight: this.outerRef.current.clientHeight });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Container ref={this.outerRef}>
          {this.state.outerHeight}
        </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

You can check on : https://codesandbox.io/embed/6yq239ljlk?fontsize=14

This works but I don't know if it's on this way you need height.

Answer (score -5):

You can declare outer tag and use on tag.

```
function App() {
  const heightApp: 100
  const Outer = styled.div`
    height: "`${heightApp}`px";
    border: 1px solid black;
  `;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Outer>Inside</Outer>
    </div>
  );
}
```